# SAS EG: How to create a join containing a filter?

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

[This problem note](http://support.sas.com/kb/20/442.html) describes a situation in EG 4.1 where you use an outer join containing a filter (i.e. the predicate is in the ON clause rather than the WHERE clause). But how do you actually tell Enterprise Guide's query builder to include a filter in a join? The problem note says this is fixed in 4.2 so did they change the user interface, or is there already an option to do this in 4.1, and the option isn't working?

Comment: If I understand the "problem note" (that's what I call an euphemism) correctly, you can work around it by moving the parts of the WHERE clause that refer to the "right" table to the ON clause.

Comment: Certainly if you edit the generated SQL but I wonder how you are supposed to tell EG that you want the filter in the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the user interface is changed. 
In SAS EG 4.3 (and probably also in EG 4.2) the Join Properties window was added a possibility to enter "Filter to include in the 'join tables on' clause".
What you enter here, won't appear in WHERE clause but will be added to the ON clause.
E.g. "your_additional_filters" in following code:

```
...
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.key = t2.key AND (your_additional_filters) )
WHERE some other conditions
```